# Compared to other algorithms, what makes Depth-first Search a better solution for counting the number of connected-components in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I've looked for ways to count the no. of connected components online. I noticed that in most sites, the algorithm used is Depth-first search. I believe you can achieve the same thing Breadth-first search and union-find as well. So why do people prefer using DFS for finding number of connected components?

Comment: I guess you were researching competitive programming resources. There, simplicity wins and DFS usually requires less code. In a real-world scenario, it might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Mainly because of two reasons:

1. It's simple and short. No data structure is required (well we need a stack but recursion takes care of that)
2. It's memory friendly, Breath First Search has a memory complexity of `O(V)` (`V` is number of nodes). DFS on the other hand has `O(h)` (`h` is maximum depth of the recursion tree).

Comment: You're saying that no data structure is required. However, I've seen an implementation of DFS where there was a boolean array which was indexed by the vertices. The purpose of the array was to mark each vertex as "visited" during the traversal. So if the array is called "visited" and if vertex 5 is visited, visited[5] is set to true.

Comment: Ok, so you're implying that DFS only uses an array as it's data structure, but other algorithms use more data structures, which makes DFS simpler. Is this one of the things that contribute to better memory complexity of DFS?

Comment: Yes. DFS, when at node `N` stores only one of `N`'s  neighbors in the stack at a time while BFS pushes all of `N`'s  neighbors into the queue at once.

Comment: While I agree with the first point of this answer (at least in the context of competitive programming, which I assume this question relates to), the second point is a bit misleading. First of all, both DFS and BFS require Ω(n) bits of bookkeeping to avoid running into cycles (unless the graph is a forest). Second of all, without lower bounds your comparison is meaningless. In fact you could flip it around and say that BFS requires only O(b^d) of space while DFS requires O(V), so BFS is better. Of course it depends on the shape of the graph, e.g. its branching factor and diameter.

Answer (score 1):

It is not better in terms of complexity, as in all cases you will visit a node exactly once. In terms of memory usage, you will always have to know what nodes were visited and what nodes were found and not visited yet. Depth-first will take a child node and visit its descendants before its siblings, while Breadth-first will visit the siblings before descendants. Depth-first is shorter and simpler and arguably more intuitive though, which could be the reason it is chosen in tutorials, books and presentation more frequently than the others.

In many cases the stack to be used is handled by recursion, but that is not necessarily a good idea, especially in the case of large graphs.